# How to close application onClick of a button in Alert Box in Android?

Tags: android, onclick

How do I close the application in Android inside `onClick()`?

My code follows something like this:

```
alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        System.out.println("cancel clicked");  
    }
});   
alertbox.show();
```

If I write `finish()` inside `onClick` it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {        
            ActivityName.this.finish();
        }              
    });   
    alertbox.show();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling finish of the main activity directly. `MainActivityName.this.finish();`